# Should I fill the mesh between two objects?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am creating a 3d character, I would like to know if I must close this area for a game?
The boots are different object from the pants, however the pants are like jeans.

I would like to know if I must put the boots inside the pants for good animation in game?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it really depends on what you want it to look like. Realistically and according to couple of games (not blender games), there should be a gap where parts of the upper leg can be seen under the pants when the camera is placed down and field of view is pointing upward towards the pants, otherwise you will end up as if the pants and skin are stuck together.

Comment: so I should close the area, and then places near the boots in this case, very close ?

Comment: @ReifusRufus no not really, realistically there should be space between the pants and legs, for the boots there is no need for space as they feet won't be appearing anyway. Could you please accept and upvote the answer if it was helpful?